# Unicorn installation error on Debian 5

Tags: debian, ruby, rubygems, unicorn

I am running ruby1.9 on Debian 5, and did not manage to install 'unicorn' with rubygems. I got this error and do not really know how to solve it.

Do you have any idea of the possible root cause ?

```
> gem install unicorn


Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing unicorn:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9 extconf.rb
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
checking for clockid_t in time.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... yes
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for poll() in poll.h... yes
checking for getaddrinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... yes
checking for getnameinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_storage in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h... yes
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... no
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_io_t.fd in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_io_t.mode in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_io_t.pathv in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... no
checking for struct RFile in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
checking size of struct RFile in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... 24
checking for struct RObject... no
checking size of int... 4
checking for rb_io_ascii8bit_binmode()... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_thread_io_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
checking for rb_time_interval()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
creating Makefile

make
cc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0 -I. -DHAVE_TYPE_CLOCKID_T -DHAVE_POLL -DHAVE_GETADDRINFO -DHAVE_GETNAMEINFO -DHAVE_TYPE_STRUCT_SOCKADDR_STORAGE -DHAVE_SYS_SELECT_H -DHAVE_RUBY_IO_H -DHAVE_RB_IO_T_FD -DHAVE_ST_FD -DHAVE_RB_IO_T_MODE -DHAVE_ST_MODE -DHAVE_TYPE_STRUCT_RFILE -DSIZEOF_STRUCT_RFILE=24 -DSIZEOF_INT=4 -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_STR_SET_LEN -DHAVE_RB_TIME_INTERVAL    -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2 -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses  -fPIC  -o kgio_ext.o -c kgio_ext.c
cc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0 -I. -DHAVE_TYPE_CLOCKID_T -DHAVE_POLL -DHAVE_GETADDRINFO -DHAVE_GETNAMEINFO -DHAVE_TYPE_STRUCT_SOCKADDR_STORAGE -DHAVE_SYS_SELECT_H -DHAVE_RUBY_IO_H -DHAVE_RB_IO_T_FD -DHAVE_ST_FD -DHAVE_RB_IO_T_MODE -DHAVE_ST_MODE -DHAVE_TYPE_STRUCT_RFILE -DSIZEOF_STRUCT_RFILE=24 -DSIZEOF_INT=4 -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_STR_SET_LEN -DHAVE_RB_TIME_INTERVAL    -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2 -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses  -fPIC  -o autopush.o -c autopush.c
cc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0 -I. -DHAVE_TYPE_CLOCKID_T -DHAVE_POLL -DHAVE_GETADDRINFO -DHAVE_GETNAMEINFO -DHAVE_TYPE_STRUCT_SOCKADDR_STORAGE -DHAVE_SYS_SELECT_H -DHAVE_RUBY_IO_H -DHAVE_RB_IO_T_FD -DHAVE_ST_FD -DHAVE_RB_IO_T_MODE -DHAVE_ST_MODE -DHAVE_TYPE_STRUCT_RFILE -DSIZEOF_STRUCT_RFILE=24 -DSIZEOF_INT=4 -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_STR_SET_LEN -DHAVE_RB_TIME_INTERVAL    -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2 -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses  -fPIC  -o wait.o -c wait.c
cc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0 -I. -DHAVE_TYPE_CLOCKID_T -DHAVE_POLL -DHAVE_GETADDRINFO -DHAVE_GETNAMEINFO -DHAVE_TYPE_STRUCT_SOCKADDR_STORAGE -DHAVE_SYS_SELECT_H -DHAVE_RUBY_IO_H -DHAVE_RB_IO_T_FD -DHAVE_ST_FD -DHAVE_RB_IO_T_MODE -DHAVE_ST_MODE -DHAVE_TYPE_STRUCT_RFILE -DSIZEOF_STRUCT_RFILE=24 -DSIZEOF_INT=4 -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_STR_SET_LEN -DHAVE_RB_TIME_INTERVAL    -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2 -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses  -fPIC  -o connect.o -c connect.c
cc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0 -I. -DHAVE_TYPE_CLOCKID_T -DHAVE_POLL -DHAVE_GETADDRINFO -DHAVE_GETNAMEINFO -DHAVE_TYPE_STRUCT_SOCKADDR_STORAGE -DHAVE_SYS_SELECT_H -DHAVE_RUBY_IO_H -DHAVE_RB_IO_T_FD -DHAVE_ST_FD -DHAVE_RB_IO_T_MODE -DHAVE_ST_MODE -DHAVE_TYPE_STRUCT_RFILE -DSIZEOF_STRUCT_RFILE=24 -DSIZEOF_INT=4 -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_STR_SET_LEN -DHAVE_RB_TIME_INTERVAL    -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2 -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses  -fPIC  -o poll.o -c poll.c

poll.c:11:18: error: st.h: No such file or directory
poll.c: In function 'do_poll':
poll.c:148: error: 'RUBY_UBF_IO' undeclared (first use in this function)
poll.c:148: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
poll.c:148: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [poll.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.0/gems/kgio-2.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.0/gems/kgio-2.5.0/ext/kgio/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are several different `st.h` header files [out there](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=st.h&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any), but given that you're missing RUBY_* constants, I'm guessing you're missing the st.h file in `ruby1.9.1-dev`

Comment: I use 1.9.0 version of ruby, do you think this can be linked ?

Comment: Well, wherever you got that version of ruby from, you should be able to get the `-dev` package from the same place.  If you didn't install from a package, then you're going to have to figure out how to get the headers from whatever you installed from, to wherever this is looking for them (looks like `/usr/include/ruby-1.9.0/`).

Answer (score 0):

check the zombie process
**ps aux | grep unicorn**
if it is kill the master process by 
**kill -9 processid**
try to install it again. i hope it will help

Comment: Zombie processes are processes which exited, but whose parent hasn't collected the exit status. So they are a symptom of badly written parent processes. By themselves, they consume a trivial amount of system resources (a PID, and a skeleton process descriptor containing the exit status and reason), so they aren't worrisome as such, only as a signal of badly written programs.